# Multiplication of digits in two linked lists

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am trying to multiply digits that are stored in two singly linked lists. However, my algorithm has turned to be getting very complex. I am doing the multiplication the way we did in elementary schools. Getting the value of one of the lists and multiplying in to each value of the other list till we cover all numbers. The problem is tat I have to add these numbers up at the end to get the final result of the multiplication, and this is where I get in to trouble. I have to find a way to be able to multiply any number of elements in to each other and be able to add the results up at the end. So far my code is like this

```
public SingleyLinkedList Multiply(SingleyLinkedList list1, 
                                  SingleyLinkedList list2)
        {
        SingleyLinkedList multiplyList = new SingleyLinkedList();
        SingleyLinkedList tempList1 = new SingleyLinkedList();
        SingleyLinkedList tempList2 = new SingleyLinkedList();

        for (int j = 0; j < list2.Size(); j++)
        {
            int carry = 0;
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(list2.GetValue(j));

            for (int k = 0; k < list1.Size(); k++)
            {

                int A = Convert.ToInt32(list1.GetValue(k));

                if (k == list1.Size()-1)
                {
                    int multiply = ((A * B) + carry);
                    multiplyList.InsertAtFront(multiply);
                    carry = 0;
                }
                if (k < list1.Size()-1)
                {
                    int multiply = ((A * B) + carry) % 10;
                    multiplyList.InsertAtFront(multiply);
                    carry = 0;
                }
                carry = (int)((A * B) / 10);
            }
        }
      //return multiplyList;

        for ( int t = 0 ; t < list2.Size() ; t++)
        {

            for (int n = 0; n < list1.Size(); n++)
            {
                int val = Convert.ToInt32(multiplyList.GetValue(n));
                tempList1.InsertAtFront(val);
            }

            // adding zero to take care of 10th                
            for (int m = 0; m < list2.Size() - 1; m++)
            {
                tempList1.InsertAtFront(0);
            }

        }

        return tempList1;`
```

After this stage, I have to pass my values to the Add method that I have created, which takes two linked lists as parameters and does the addition. I need to be able to do this process for as many numbers as I desire. 
Any suggestion or if you know of any better way to do the multiplication at all?

Comment: Can  you more clearly define your requirements?

Comment: It can be a dot product, but not necessarily. I want to multiply 3541 by 352. my program creates two singly linked lists {1,4,5,3} and{2,5,3}. then the elements get multiplied one by one and a temp list of {10,6, 2,3,17,7,0,5,7,0,8,2} is created.I have to build up the multiplication result from this linkedlist. May be there is a better way to do this, but I don't know yet.

Comment: Yes there's a better way to do that.  use the built-in multiplication functionality.  why do you have to use the linked lists?

Comment: So is this meant to be a teaching tool that allows you to show how the multiplication would look if written down as long multiplication?

Comment: I have built my own Singly Linked List class and I am building my own multiplication method. The whole point is to this by myself and not using methods and classes provided by .Net

Comment: @user843681 If you're just doing this on your own to figure out how the computer actually does multiplication, that you're barking up the wrong tree.  You probably should be learning about Computer Architecture, and all the And-Gates, Or-Gates Mutexes, adders, latches, registers, ALU's  and whatnot, and then from there learn some assembly.

Comment: @user843681 - Isn't that a bit like growing your own wheat in order to make a cheese sandwich?

Comment: @SamIam: I was going to say the same. Binary adding machine... Great book for that: http://www.amazon.com/Code-Language-Computer-Hardware-Software/dp/0735611319

Answer (score 0):

this looks like an un-necessaraly complex implimentation of a simple problem.  Smells like homework.

You mentioned that you're having trouble adding up the values in the end(like you would in long-multiplication.

I would suggest implementing a `sum` method, and also using a `sum` list.

initialize your sum list to 0, and then after every iteration of the multiplication process, use the `sum` method to add you new list to the `sum` list.

Alternatively, you can have a List of Lists for the first part of your multiplication, and then sum all of those lists together at the end.

This implementation will take a little bit more memory, but it will also be a little easier to visualize.

Comment: Are you talking about the sum method from Linq ? I can not use that. That is the condition of the challenge.

Comment: @user843681 can you make your own sum method?

Comment: I have already created. it is addLists(SinglyLinkedList list1, SinglyLinkedList list2). It takes two singly linked lists and does a bunch of stuff on the digits and creates a final linked list that contains the addition result digits in proper order. I have already created this method and it works properly.

Comment: @user843681 Great!  now just use it to add the results of your multiplication

Comment: the issue is picking up the digits from temp list. for example a list like {10,6, 2,3,17,7,0,5,7,0,8,2} has to change to change to list1 {10,6,2,3}, {17,7,0,5}, and {7,0,8,2} to be passed to the add method.

Comment: @user843681  don't cram all your results to add into one linked list.  keep them separate.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to replicate this java code.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MultiplyTwoLinkedLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> number1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> number2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        number1.addFirst(1);
        number1.addFirst(2);

        number2.addFirst(1);
        number2.addFirst(2);

        multiply(number1, number2);
    }

    public static int multiply(LinkedList<Integer> n1, LinkedList<Integer> n2){

        int placeValue1 = 1;
        int sum=0;
        for(int digit1 : n1){
            int placeValue2 = 1;
            for(int digit2 : n2){
                sum+=((digit1*placeValue1) * (digit2*placeValue2));
                placeValue2=placeValue2*10;
            }
            placeValue1=placeValue1*10;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        return 1;
    }


}
```